# Conversion of data type in pandas column while plotting using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, seaborn, data-science

I have been trying to plot the price vs. km/100L from my dataset using seaborn regplot. I have tried converting the data type of both the columns to int64,but it doesnt work.

```
automobile_df["price"].astype("int64")
automobile_df["km/100L"].astype("int64")
```

Then I tried plotting price vs. km/100L using regplot from the seaborn library.

```
sns.regplot(x="km/100L",y="price",data="automobile_df")
```

The complete error message I get is,

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-fdf8be478666> in <module>()
----> 1 sns.regplot(x="km/100L",y="price",data="temp_df")


/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/seaborn/regression.py in regplot(x, y, data, x_estimator, x_bins, x_ci, scatter, fit_reg, ci, n_boot, units, seed, order, logistic, lowess, robust, logx, x_partial, y_partial, truncate, dropna, x_jitter, y_jitter, label, color, marker, scatter_kws, line_kws, ax)
    807                                  order, logistic, lowess, robust, logx,
    808                                  x_partial, y_partial, truncate, dropna,
--> 809                                  x_jitter, y_jitter, color, label)
    810 
    811     if ax is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/seaborn/regression.py in __init__(self, x, y, data, x_estimator, x_bins, x_ci, scatter, fit_reg, ci, n_boot, units, seed, order, logistic, lowess, robust, logx, x_partial, y_partial, truncate, dropna, x_jitter, y_jitter, color, label)
    107         # Extract the data vals from the arguments or passed dataframe
    108         self.establish_variables(data, x=x, y=y, units=units,
--> 109                                  x_partial=x_partial, y_partial=y_partial)
    110 
    111         # Drop null observations

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/seaborn/regression.py in establish_variables(self, data, **kws)
     43         for var, val in kws.items():
     44             if isinstance(val, str):
---> 45                 vector = data[val]
     46             elif isinstance(val, list):
     47                 vector = np.asarray(val)

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem is because `astype()` returns a copy by default (see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)), so you will have to assign the result to the same column like this:

```
automobile_df["price"] = automobile_df["price"].astype("int64")
automobile_df["km/100L"] = automobile_df["km/100L"].astype("int64")
```

Or if you just want to change the type when plotting, use it like this

```
sns.regplot(x=automobile_df["km/100L"].astype("int64"),y=automobile_df["price"].astype("int64"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only providing a string for data, namely the name of your dataframe. Instead, it should be the dataframe itself, so no quotation marks. Please also make sure that `x` and `y` are the correct names if the columns in your dataframe.